# How to seperate strings from a serialized XML node

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have an serialized XML file. This shows the relevant part:
[image]

I am reading this XML file with this (code snippet):

```
            temp = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(s);
            var document = new XmlDocument();
            document.Load(s);

            var root = document.DocumentElement;
            var node = root["ScenarioDescription"];
            var text = node?.InnerText;
            var ArmyNode = root["ArmyFiles"];
            var ArmyText = ArmyNode?.InnerText;
```

However, ArmyText returns the concatenation of all three strings that make up the ArmyFiles node. I need them as three separate strings. How can I do this?

Comment: Please include the XML as text. It makes it easier for someone to copy/paste into their own tests.

Comment: These are very large XML files (1,000s of lines). I don't think pasting it all in as text is practical. I just want to read the 3 strings that make up a node.

Comment: No, but you could paste the part that's in your screenshot. That's all I meant. The point is to lower the barrier for someone to help you by making it easier to start up a test.

Answer (score 0):

This code works to read all the strings in the node and place them into a list:

```
                foreach (XmlElement A in ArmyNode)
            {
                var ArmyTemp = A.InnerText;
                ArmyList.Add(ArmyTemp);
            }

                var ArmyText = ArmyNode?.InnerText;
```